# keeping a local variable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to add a pagination to my app for this reason i coded below code but there is a problem.

Here is my useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    let x = null;
    const unsubscribe = chatsRef
      .orderBy("createdAt", "desc")
      .limit(10)
      .onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
        const messagesFirestore = querySnapshot
          .docChanges()
          .filter(({ type }) => type === "added")
          .map(({ doc }) => {
            const message = doc.data();

            x = message;

            return { ...message, createdAt: message.createdAt.toDate() };
          });

        appendMessages(messagesFirestore);

        if (latestMessage != null) {
          if (
            new Date(
              latestMessage["createdAt"]["seconds"] * 1000 +
                latestMessage["createdAt"]["nanoseconds"] / 1000000
            ) >
            new Date(
              x["createdAt"]["seconds"] * 1000 +
                x["createdAt"]["nanoseconds"] / 1000000
            )
          ) {
            latestMessage = x;
          }
        } else {
          latestMessage = x;
        }
      });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

I got the data from my database and i saved the oldest data in to `latestMessage` (for pagination) but the problem is that:

I declared my `latestMessage` out of my function like that:

```
let latestMessage = null;
export default function ChatTutor({ route }) {
...
}
```

And I passed my props to ChatTutor component (chatRoomId, username...) and according to that id, the room and its data are rendered. But the `latestMessage` always set some value and when i go to parent component and clicked another chatRoom, ChatTutor has a value of `latestMessage`'s other value(oldest value). How can i set `latestMessage` null when i go to the parent ?

Comment: did you consider using unmount lifecycle useEffect hook? There you can just clean it up.

Comment: But I want to clean it up just when i go to parent component. Does it work in that situation?@TukaramBhosale

Comment: when you navigate away from child, it will get unmounted, I hope it should work in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-instance-variables) to store local mutable data (it would not participate in re-renders):

```
export default function ChatTutor({ route }) {
  const latestMessage = useRef(null);  // null is initial value
  // ...
  latestMessage.current = 'some new message' // set data
  console.log(latestMessage.current) // read data
  return <>ChatTutor Component</>
}
```